# Trouble Validating Required Text in textarea with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I have a textarea that I am trying to validate whether someone has filled out or not before submitted the form. I'm doing all of my validation server side with PHP.

I had two thoughts. Either:

1) submit the form to itself and have the fields validate themselves on the same page and then redirect to the page where the form would update my database. The problem I had was that since it was posting to itself, once the page redirected, I couldn't carry out using the POST values because they were no longer valid.

2) So I figured I'd just do the validation on the second page (the page that the form initially is set to post to). Here's my code for that page, where 'description' is the name of the textarea:

```
session_start();
if(!$_POST['description']){
echo "<script>alert(\"Please fill out all fields\");</script>";
header("location:post_job.php");
}
```

And then it redirects back to the page where the form is being filled. I get this error though:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at siteinfo/site/checkjob.php:4) in siteinfo/site/checkjob.php on line 5
```

Line five is the header line (so line four is obviously the echo line). I don't understand why it would create that error since I haven't sent a header yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `header()` use `window.location.href="post_job.php"` inside the `<script>` tag

Comment: Because we cannot use echo just before header("location:)

Comment: The better approach will be an javascript alert `(alert();)` in case of javascript based validation and an php alert `(echo/print etc.)` in case of php based validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
session_start();
if(!$_POST['description']){
echo "<script>alert(\"Please fill out all fields\");";
echo "window.location.href='post_job.php';";
echo "</script>";
}
```

Although I must add the way you intend to show your message isn't in a good manner. Validating through Ajax or javascript before the form is submitted is a good route to follow. Keep this way as a backup plan in case javascript is disabled on the client's system.

Comment: That's what I had planned to do (validate through javascript before sending the form) but was I approaching that wrong? I would have it submit to itself, correct? How do I retain the $_POST variables once the page is redirected.

Comment: The problem with this is that it is still inserting it into the database so it doesn't actually prevent the form from posting...

Comment: If you want to retain the values once a form is submitted, you'll have to use `if(isset($_POST[<insert button name here>])){echo $_POST['<insert element name here>']}` inside the `value` attribute of the element. However, since there is a redirection in your case the values won't be saved.

Answer (score 0):

The echo with the  tag in it sends output to the browser. Use your preferred JavaScript way of redirecting within the script tag instead.

Comment: I can't find a way to use Javascript to validate the textarea.